# Accessing Rest API for kafka schema registry using server on same domain

Tags: javascript, cors, apache-kafka

I have kafka set up on my machine with schema registry enabled.

I am also writing a Flask application on my same machine.

I need to access the Rest API i.e.

```
localhost:8081/schemas/ids/1
```

From

```
localhost:5000
```

How do I achieve this?

I am using latest version of kafka and schema registry.. and have tried using JavaScript CORS request

EDIT

Here is the properties file

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

Here is the error

[image]

Here is the logs

[image]

Comment: not sure how CORS comes into play. What error do you get when you call http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/1 directly? What about if you just run `curl localhost:8081/schemas/ids/1` from a shell outside of flask?

Comment: I think it has to do with CORS because the error I get is `XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No Access Control Allow Origin header is present...`. I've tried using a JavaScript CORS function I found online to no avail. If I go to the kafka schema registry rest API URL directly in browser it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following config parameters to your etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties file to enable CORS

`access.control.allow.methods=GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
access.control.allow.origin=*`

Full documentation for config params is here http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/config.html

Comment: I tried this as well as adding those lines to kafka server properties.. no luck

Comment: Also, should you be able to use a basic ajax request in this case.. without finding CORS functions

Comment: Not Kafka server, this has to go in schema-registry.properties and then you need to restart SR

Comment: Try a more complete list of methods GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS and check your SR log for more debug info.

Comment: It's picking up the comments from your config file. Remove the inline comments from your config file or put them on a separate line beginning with '#'